# Як правильно - "найбагатший" чи "найбагатіший"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Гугл за пошуковим рядком "найбагатший чи найбагатіший" прямим  текстом [каже](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=g5IaWuvMD6Xi8Ae29x8)

> Можливо, ви мали на увазі: найбагатший чи **найбагатший**

З ним погоджується ТСН,

> Десятку **найбагатших** людей України вкотре очолив одіозний Ренат
>   Ахметов. Видання "Фокус" оприлюднило список ста **найбагатших**...

Вікіпедія

> спираються на дані американського фінансового журналу «Forbes», який
>   публікує, починаючи з 1987 року, щорічний список **найбагатших** людей
>   світу.

та багато інших.  Але в німецькому Вікшионарі чогось [відмінюють](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9) слово **найбагатіший**. Також бачив  у І. Нечуй-Левицького

> Єремія був **найбагатіший** за всіх магнатів, гордий та високодумний

Та й [в інтернеті вистачає](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA482zgtzXAhWCbZoKHfiqBREQvgUIIygB&biw=1465&bih=769) використання слова **найбагатіший**.

Чому **найбагатший** — правильна форма? Чим обумовлене вживання форми **найбагатіший**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Правопис наростків — § 20<sub>32</sub>](//r2u.org.ua/node/226) — ПП 1928

> **-ІШИЙ**, **-ШИЙ** *32.* У 2 ступені, прикметників пишемо **-іший** (а не **-ійший**, **-іщий**): *стар**і́**ший*, *мил**і́**ший*, *добр**і́**ший*, *весел**і́**ший*, *сильн**і́**ший*, *гаряч**і́**ший* і т. ін.
>
> Про **-ший** після приголосних (**-дший.** **-тший** і т. ін.) див. *§ 16<sub>3</sub>*.

[Зміни приголосних при збігові їх — § 16<sub>3</sub>](//r2u.org.ua/node/184)

> **2 ступінь прикметн.** *3.* У 2 ступені прикметників (прислівників), коли до пня додається наросток **-ший** (**-ше**, **-ша**), то **з** + **ший** змінюється в **-жчий**, а **с** + **ший** у **-щий**: *ни**зь**ки́й* — *ни́**жч**ий*, *ву**зь**ки́й* — *ву́**жч**ий*, *кра́**с**ний* — *кра́**щ**ий*, *ви**с**о́кий* — *ви́**щ**ий* і т. ін.
>
> Усі інші приголосні перед **-ший** на письмі зберігаються: *соло́**д**ший*, *шви́**д**ший*, *коро́**т**ший*, *то́**н**ший*, *м’я́**к**ший* і т. ін.

---

Ріжниці наче нема, просто є деякі правила зміни при виборі наростка **-ший**, хоча змістовим сенсом теж можуть [ріжнитися](http://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/6-1-0-101).

> ґ) приголосні **т**, **д** перед **-ш-** звучать як **ч**, **дж**, але на письмі ця зміна не позначається: *короткий* — *корот­ший* [*корочший*], *багатий* — *багатший* [*багачший*], *молодий* — *молодший* [*молоджший*], *гладкий* — *гладший* [*гладжший*].
>
> Деякі прикметники можуть мати паралельні форми вищо­го ступеня порівняння — з суфіксом **-іш-** і з суфіксом **-ш-**. Ці форми нерідко різняться відтінками свого лексичного значен­ня: *старіший* (за віком) і *старший* (за становищем), ***багатіший* (стосується лише матеріальних цінностей)** і ***багатший* (сто­сується і змісту)**, *здоровіший* (за станом здоровʼя й за розміра­ми) і *здоровший* (за станом здоровʼя), *товстіший* (стосується лише осіб) і *товщий* (стосується і предметів).

Answer (score 0):

По-перше, google, ТСН, вікіпедія не є авторитетними джерелами, коли мова йде про перевірку на правопис або існування слова. Для даної цілі слугують орфографічні словники.

По-друге, вам варто було б повторити правила утворення ступенів порівняння прикметників. Правила кажуть, що вищий та найвищий ступінь утворюється шляхом додавання суфікса **"-іш-"** або **"-ш-"** до основи. Тому нормативними є обидві форми, які, проте, можуть відрізнятися семантично (як, наприклад, *найстаріший* — *найстарший*).

**P.S.** Я виступаю за закриття даного питання, оскільки, на мій погляд, воно не несе академічної цінності та не проявило елементарних дослідницьких дій з боку автора.

Comment: Чи варто якомусь з цих варіантів віддавати перевагу?